# Why is the admin bar appearing (on certain pages) for non logged-in users?

Tags: admin-bar

The admin bar is appearing for non logged-in users on one of my sites, but only for two specific pages (/work and /contact, for what it's worth). Has anyone heard of this happening before? It appears as though one of the site's users is logged in (their username is displayed), but clicking any links on the admin bar lead to the login page. If I click Log Out under that users name in the admin bar, I get a prompt to ensure I want to logout, then a redirect to /wp-login.php. However, upon returning to /work or /contact, the admin bar still appears.

Comment: Page got cached by something?

Comment: Huh. Emptying all caches in W3 Total Cache fixed it. Add as an answer and I'll accept. Seems like an issue with that plugin that should be fixed.

Comment: Change line 213 of admin-bar.php in the wp-includes folder from return to die.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I think that mis-identifying all users not-logged in is extremely unlikely, my line of thought is that wrong non-public version of page was cached for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found that clearing the cache tempoparily solved it...
I started suspecting w3 Total cache and found this answer: https://www.thewebmaster.com/dev/2015/may/6/wordpress-admin-bar-shows-logged-out/

In short go to W3 Total Cache/Page Cache settings and make sure "Don't cache pages for logged in users" is ticked.  Otherwise it will cache the page as the logged-in user sees it.

Answer (score 0):

i has the same problem. it was caused by the following plugin: WP-Optimize – Cache, Clean, Compress.
By David Anderson, Ruhani Rabin,and Team Updraft.
After removing the plugin and using WordPress super cache by automatic, my issue was resolved

Answer (score 0):

I'm also seeing this issue with the WP-Optimize – Cache, Clean, Compress plugin. Deactivating the plugin seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/266038)

Comment: This was a reason I was seeing the same thing and so in that way it was answering the question.